# How to search for two patterns and write out a different line based on the results

Tags: unix, awk, sed, scripting, grep

I have twenty thousand plus archived files to search through for a certain pattern and want to output the 4th line of each file from the results.  Yes the files Is this possible using grep?

The data looks like this:

```
UNA:+.? '
UNB+UNOC:1+XXX:ZZ+ZZZ:14+140726:0215+AA000083308210++INVOIC'
UNH+1+INVOIC:D:98A:UN'
BGM+380+4161846758'
DTM+3:20140725:102'
DTM+140:20140908:102'
RFF+ON:4501161623'
NAD+SU+2024241::90++WSWSInternational bvba/sprl        +DeereResearchpark Zone 3:Geldenaaksebaan 464:B-XCXCLeuven, BELGIUM:.++++BE'
RFF+VA:BE0403593343'
RFF+VR:2024241'
NAD+PS+5050083901044::9++Wimble Manufacturing Belgium BVBA+:::EGGESTR 1++++BE'
RFF+VA:BE0838369020'
NAD+DP+::9++LABO PRINGLES+:::HOMBEEKSESTWG 323'
CUX+2:EUR:4'
```

So, I want to search on NAD+SU, NAD+PS and if "+:::" can be found then write to a new file or printscreen the line containing BGM, which always is the 4th line down.
Thanks

Comment: I don't see where there is `+:::` 4 lines above the `BGM` line. Please simplify/clarify your sample data. Also, S.O. isn't a free coding service, you're expected to post an attempt at solving your problem or at least explain where you're having trouble. That said, good luck!

Comment: Hi shelter, my level of using grep comes only in this format

Comment: grep -il "NAD+SU" `grep -il "NAD+PS" *20140728*`

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -name 'archived.files.pattern' -print0 |
while read -d '' -r filename; do
    if grep -Eq '^NAD\+(SU|PS).*\+:::' "$filename"; then
        sed -n '4{p;q}' "$filename"
    fi
done
```

Using `find` to print the list of "archived files" -- with 20 000 files, may get "argument list too long" errors.  Assuming GNU find for `-print0` action.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS, this should do it:

```
$ awk -v RS='^$' -F'\n' '/(^|\n)NAD\+(SU|PS)[^\n]*\+:::/{ print FILENAME, $4 }' file1 ... file20000
```

or if you prefer:

```
$ find <whatever> | xargs awk -v RS='^$' -F'\n' '/(^|\n)NAD\+(SU|PS)[^\n]*\+:::/{ print FILENAME, $4 }'
```

Remove the `FILENAME,` if you don't need the file name printed before each output line. Use `find <whatever> -print0 | xargs -0 awk...` if the file names can contain newlines.

Comment: Yes, there's nothing shell specific there.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an awk script executed (with multiple files) from find:

```
find . -name 'file.pattern' -execdir awk '
  FNR==4 {bgm = $0}
  FNR==8 && index($0, "+:::") ||
  FNR==11 && index($0, "+:::") {print bgm}
' {} +
```

The awk script is simple minded, assuming that the line numbers don't change at all across files. If they do, substitute Ed Morton's script.